# Visual studio references to cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

How can I add some links between files to allow jumping from different cpp/h files included into Visual Studio 2013.

Like: writing code into A.cpp - in code comments allow jump to B.cpp. I have a lot of tabs, and spending a lot of time for switching. Very big project

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. Are you looking for [<see>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx) in documentation comments?

Comment: Find a litle bit that i seach - combination Ctrl + , and Ctrl + ; . Then install VS Productive Power Tool and use Ctrl + Click. But i still looking for another thing.

Have comments like:
/* add class to vector at Foo.cpp */
/* add class to startup settings at bar.cpp */

I'd like clicked on it that openning tabs in VS2013

Comment: I know that if a line in the Output window starts with the file name and line number, you can double-click to go to that line of the file. I don't know if there's any way to do the same with a code comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very elegant, but you could do this workaround.
Write in A.cpp:

```
#if(0)
#include "B.cpp"
#endif
```

Then you can place the cursor above "B.cpp" and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or right-click and select "Open document B.cpp"

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + tab will give you a shortcut to move between code tabs, although it won't bring you directly to  specific tab

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the necessary file might not even be open in a tab yet.